# Adding dll reference to asp.net mvc application without restarting application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll

I'm trying to add new dlls to my application. I've tried using Ninject:

```
var standardKernel = new StandardKernel();
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(standardKernel));
standardKernel.Load<MyPluginBootstrapper>();
standardKernel.Bind<IHelloWorldService>().To<HelloWorldService>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyDependencyResolver(standardKernel));
```

I've tried using:

```
var _fullPluginPath = Path.Combine(path, "App2.Plugin.dll");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(Assembly.LoadFrom(_fullPluginPath).GetName());
```

And I always got the same error when I try to access to a controller that is in that new dll:

```
Compilation Error
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App2' could not be found (are     you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization;
Line 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 28:     using App2.Plugin;
Line 29:     
Line 30:     

Source File: c:\Users\wilhem\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0c41d57d\e08d7bc3\App_Web_index.cshtml.244a139d.hzhandta.0.cs    Line: 28
```

I'm implementing like a plugins based architecture and I want the ability to add new dlls without restart the application. Any idea with the code above?

Answer (score 3):

You can load assemblies on the go. But do not put it inside your application `/bin` directory.
Put it on another location, like `/plugins`. Do not let it be public visible.

Create a public interface in which is previously know, with functions like `IMyInterface.DoStuff()` and return an string, whatever.

Then you can use reflection to call it:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Server.MapPath("~/plugins/myDll.dll"));
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyClass");
object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Make sure your MyClass implements your commom `IMyInterface`.
You won't be able to see your classes like:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

This would reset your ASP.NET application.
But with reflection, you will be able to do something like:

```
string myReturn = ((IMyInterface)instanceOfMyType).DoStuff();
```

Comment: My dll is a asp.net mvc application that has controllers inside. I'm building the controller factory and registering all that stuff. I can achieve this using BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(MyDll) but this method can be used only in PreApplicationStartMethod, even y try to use Ninject and I got the same error. I don't want call any method directly, I just want to reference my dll to my mvc main application.

Comment: Is there a major reason for not restarting the MVC application? If you add new views to your application, I don't see why you cant reset it. Even plugin technologies sometimes requires you application to restart for wiring some events. Also there is no way to compile a class that is not know at compile time! How I said, you need to create interfaces and route information through your loaded dlls, because this will be known at compile time.

Comment: I understand what you say, I've created all that structure, routing, interfaces, etc...The problem restarting the app is that I will lost sessions in the application, maybe I should create like a maintenance task and restart the application early in the morning after add a new plugin. But I prefer add a plugin without restart the main application, I can load the new links to the news views into the index page within the main application dynamically without restart.

Comment: I would say that you should never let your application pool living for too long. You should restart it in a regular basis in order you don't run out of memory in your server. You can try using a webfarm for that, with sessions saved on SQL Server. Then your users would not be logged out.

Comment: Yes, definitely that can be a solution using a SQL server to store the sessions.